# Windows BackupRead / BackupWrite and ACLs

Tags: security, winapi, backup, usability, acl

I have been trying to understand what should be the right way in using BackupRead and BackupWrite for backing up data on a computer and especially about restoring it reliably.

Now I understand how to use the API and have been successful. However there's one thing that bothers me. 
You can backup, beside the file content itself, any alternate data streams also the security information (ACLs).

Now if I would store the ACL data for backup and then later, once the data needs to be restored on a different machine OR a newly setup machine what should I do with the SIDs which are related to the ACL?
The SID is most likely no longer valid for the machine and how should the right user be selected?
Now I am looking at this on a bigger scale let's say this is a computer with multiple users and hundreds or thousands of objects with different settings this would be mess to get the data restored with the security settings applied to them again.

Is this something, if the user of the software wishes to backup the security settings, what the user has to take about himself and update them accordingly or what?

Additionally BackupRead and BackupWrite will give me the raw binary data of those items which is not all too hard to use however obviously this API does not even intend to face this issue.

Anyone has an idea how a backup application should handle this situation? What is your thought, or any pointers on guidelines for this specific topic?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you understand correctly the problems with backup and restore of data. I think that correct understanding of problems is a half of its solving. I suppose that you are, like the most of users of the stackoverflow site, mostly software developer and not an administrator of a large network. So you see on the problem from another side of software developer and not from the side of the administrator. An administrator knows the restrictions of backup and restore of ACLs and already use it.

In general you should understand that the main purpose of backups to save the data and to restore the data later **on the same computer** or server. Another standard case is: one restore backup from one server to another server after the changing of hardware. In the case the old server will no more exist. Mostly one makes backups of servers and organize to work on the clients so, that **no** important data will be saved of the client computer.

In the most cases the backed up data has Domain Groups SIDs, Domain Users SIDs, [well-known SIDs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330) or SID aliases from the `BUILTIN` domain in the security descriptors. In the case one need make no changes of SIDs at all. If the administrator do will make some changes in ACL he can use different existing utilities like [SubInACL.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e8ba3e56-d8fe-4a91-93cf-ed6985e3927b&displaylang=en).

If you write Backup/Restore software which you want use for **moving the data** with the security information you can include in the backup some additional meta-information about the local SIDs of accounts/groups used in the saved security descriptors. In the Restore software you can provide the possibilities to replace SIDs from the saved security descriptors. Many year ago I wrote for one large customer some utilities to clear up the SIDs in SD in the file system, registry and services after domain migration. It was not so complex. So I suggest that you could implement the same feature in you Backup/restore software.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe the Backup* APIs are primarily intended to backup and restore on the same machine, which would render the SID problem irrelevant. However, assuming a scenario where you need to restore a backup on a new install, here's my thoughts on solutions.

For well-known SIDs such as Everyone, Creator Owner and so on, there isn't really any problem.

For domain dependent SIDs you can store them as is, and upon restore you could fixup the domain part, if needed. Likely you should store the domain name as well for such SIDs.

For local users and groups, you should at least store the user/group name for each SID. Fixup on restore could be partially automatic based on these names, or manual (assuming an user interface for the application) where you ask the user whether he wishes to map this user to a new local user, convert these SIDs to a well-known SID, or keep as is.

Most of the issues related to such SIDs can (and probably typically will) be possible to handle automatically. I'd certainly appreciate a backup application that was smart enough to do the restore I asked it to and figure out that "Erik" on the old machine must be "Erik" on the new machine as well.

And a side note, if you do decide to go with such a solution, remember how annoying it is to start an overnight data transfer just to get back to something 5% done blocking on a popup it could just as easily defer :)