# Can ACLs / ACEs be broken when using MoveFileEx, CreateDirectoryEx, Get/SetNamedSecurityInfo

Tags: winapi

I am archiving files and want to retain the same ACL on the folders **when moving them to different volumes** / network shares using the winapi.

For files I use MoveFileEx and for directories I use CreateDirectoryEx with the sourceDir as template and then Get/SetNamedSecurityInfo and copy all the entries to the archived version.

Will I retain the same permissions with fully functional inheritance?
Or could it be that there will be broken ACLs (broken inheritance) because I am moving between different volumes?

This article https://blog.varonis.com/fix-windows-permissions-by-brian-vecci/ (very old) states that this could happen:

> Broken ACL’s can occur for several reasons. Some automated copy programs have been known to produce unexpected results. Home-grown scripts can also produce these issues. Another inconsistency can be caused when someone simply moves a file or folder from one folder on a volume to another folder  on the same volume with different permissions. When a file or folder is moved intra-volume, it is really just being renamed in the file allocation table and its permissions do not change. When a file or folder is moved inter-volume (from one volume to another) it inherits the permissions of its new parent.

Comment: You could also get the full security descriptor (Owner, Group, DACL, Label) beforehand and set it in the `lpSecurityAttributes` when you call `CreateDirectoryEx`. In contrast, when you create the directory with the default security, it inherits from the parent directory until you overwrite the security via `SetNamedSecurityInfo`.

Comment: That's a good point. But how do I get the "overall" security descriptor? I only know of the owner descriptor, group descriptor, dacl descriptor, sacl descriptor that I can get from GetNamedSecurityInfo. How do I get the complete descriptor?

Comment: In Windows 7, get the owner, group, label, DACL (includes control flags), and SACL (includes control flags) information. Getting the SACL (i.e. audit ACEs) requires SeSecurityPrivilege to be enabled. The label info is actually in the SACL, but getting it doesn't require SeSecurityPrivilege. Windows 8 adds resource properties and CAP IDs, plus an overall backup information that gets everything. The latter requires SeSecurityPrivilege, plus apparently it requires explicitly requesting the SACL to ensure the file/directory is opened with `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ***can*** try to do this the official / normal way (you already mentioned Get/SetNamedSecurityInfo). But there are other options which do a real 1:1 transfer of the security descriptor.

---

**Option 1**

Open the file with `CreateFile` function and `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` for `dwFlagsAndAttributes`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx

Use `BackupRead` and `BackupWrite` calls for transferring the data:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362509.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362511.aspx

These two functions do not only copy the normal data, but also the security descriptor and the NTFS alternate data streams (if they exist). You can even use them to copy a directory similar to a file.
See also this article in SO:

[Windows BackupRead / BackupWrite and ACLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293498/windows-backupread-backupwrite-and-acls)

Don’t forget to enable the privileges SE_BACKUP_NAME and SE_RESTORE_NAME

---

**Option 2**

Similar to option 1, but not using `BackupRead` and `BackupWrite`, instead copying the file data with the normal way.

Then:
Use `GetKernelObjectSecurity` / `SetKernelObjectSecurity` to read and write the security descriptor:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446641.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379578.aspx

Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364399.aspx in the last paragraph for an explanation.

***Important notice:***
The documentation for SetKernelObjectSecurity contains the warning that this function should not be used for setting the permission in file systems.

Background:

Mostly because of inheritance ...

Microsoft implemented the inheritance feature only as pseudo inheritance. Every object (file, directory) still contains all relevant access control entries (ACEs). But these contain a flag if they were inherited from the parent. In this case, the ACL editor in the Windows explorer shows them as grayed out.

If you use `SetNamedSecurityInfo` for setting the ACL of a directory with some ACEs marked for inheritance and this directory contains say 100000 sub directories and files and none of the sub dirs have blocked inheritance, this will automatically lead to setting the security descriptor of all these 100000 objects.

The system DLL `NTMARTA.DLL` is responsible for this kind of “recursion”.
If all ACLs of these sub objects are set correctly (in terms of ACE order, inheritance flags...) this is basically a good thing, because the OS handles this for you.

But if some objects have ACLs with wrong entries, these can lead to even more damage.

Now, if you use `SetKernelObjectSecurity`, you have to handle all the work which is normally done by `NTMARTA.DLL` yourself.

The big advantage of `SetKernelObjectSecurity`, if used correctly:

It can overwrite objects with wrong entries in every case. There can be cases where `SetNamedSecurityInfo` is not able to correct defective ACLs (perhaps created by older tools which do not know about inheritance).

I have written a program for managing the file and folder permission of file systems, which uses `SetKernelObjectSecurity`. This tool allows to use “managed folders” which cannot be renamed / deleted by the business users (they can only delete / rename below). In addition, it handles all the list permissions needed (to be able to walk down) for upper folders automatically.

We use this for setting file systems with millions of files and for thousands of users. This is in production for over 5 years without any problems.

If you have further questions, don't hesitate to ask. The Windows permissioning is a quite complex topic, and I am happy if I can share some of the knowledge I have collected in my years as a previous Windows admin (starting with NT4) and developer.

---

... searching in my source code repository for some old stuff I wrote many years ago ...

```
    // omitting the CreateFile opening here and error handling too :-)
    // and also the creation of a buffer (it is a BYTE[])
    // ... just the copy loop


    LPVOID lpContextRead, lpContextWrite;

    lpContextRead = NULL;
    lpContextWrite = NULL;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        bSuccess = BackupRead(hRead, bBuffer, sizeof (bBuffer), 
                &dwBytesRead, FALSE, TRUE, &lpContextRead);

        if (!bSuccess) 
        {
            // ... error exit
        }

        if (!dwBytesRead) break;

        bSuccess = BackupWrite(hWrite, bBuffer, dwBytesRead, 
                &dwBytesWritten, FALSE, TRUE, &lpContextWrite);

        if (!bSuccess) 
        {
            // ... error exit
        }
    }

    // cleanup 
    BackupRead(hRead, bBuffer, 0, &dwBytesRead, TRUE, TRUE, &lpContextRead);
    BackupWrite(hWrite, bBuffer, 0, &dwBytesWritten, TRUE, TRUE, &lpContextWrite);

    CloseHandle(hRead);
    CloseHandle(hWrite);
```

Comment: Thank you Rainer, it's great to know there is someone who knows all about this stuff, I will come back to you if I have additional questions.

I will look into BackupRead and BackupWrite. 

Right now I handle the inheritance problem like this:
Starting from the top level directory: 
1. Move files only;
2. SetNamedSecurityInfo for this directory;
3. Copy subfolders;

This way only files on the top level of this folder inherit the permissions.

Comment: After trying BackupRead, BackupWrite I had some issues... is it correct that the buffer I allocate for BackupRead contains the stream data? And I pass the stream data along to BackupWrite? I somehow don't get it to work.

Comment: Yes you are right. I added an extract of a small sample I wrote many years ago. You have to pay attention to the last parameter (context handle) of BackupRead / BackupWrite. See the MSDN docu.

Comment: I have everything more or less like you. My buffer is of size 4096. I use int bufferSize = 4096. And Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize) to get the PtrInt. I am using C# and I get a `"System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'"` on my `BackupWrite()`

Comment: I created a new question with sample code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394124/c-sharp-backupread-backupwrite-system-accessviolationexception

Comment: I read your new question. I also do a lot C#, it is currently my main language... I have some ideas, but have to re-check... I will post there.